# Spring data-jdbc dependencies autoconfigures Datasource and JDBCTemplate?

Tags: spring-data, datasource, jdbctemplate, spring-data-jdbc

In a spring test there was the question:
"Would Spring Data JDBC dependency autoconfigure a Datasource and a JDBCTemplate?"

I would say no because, you need a database connector dependency like h2 or oracle right to autoconfigure a datasource? And a JDBCTemplate needs also always a datasource?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect what you think is correct, also the wording is a litte off.

Strictly speaking *[Spring Data JDBC](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-jdbc)* doesn't do any autoconfiguration at all.

Autoconfiguration is done by Spring Boot in cooperation with the *[Spring Boot Spring Data JDBC starter](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc)* which depends on (i.e. includes the auotconfiguration done by the *[Spring Boot Starter JDBC](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-jdbc)*

And that's the one actually autoconfiguring a `Datasource` and if a `Datasource` is available also provides/configures a `JdbcTemplate`.

In order to be able to configure a `Datasource` at the very least a JDBC Driver is required.
Depending on the environment (is it a in memory database or not, are you in a test execution or not) possibly also some configuration properties like a JDBC URL is required as well.

If you want to understand better what the conditions are for autoconfiguration I recommend the list of [Spring Boot autoconfiguration classes](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-auto-configuration-classes.html#auto-configuration-classes).
If you search that list for e.g. "datasource" you'll find the relevant classes and links to their source code and annotations which I think are somewhat understandable even when you don't yet understand how Spring Boot works internally exactly.